# How can I calculate the energy of Electromagnetic wave for specific range of wavelength?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

I have captured a wide bandwidth of electromagnetic waves (E and B fields) in the simulation. I would like to calculate the energy within a specific bandwidth. How can this be achieved? Which method is correct? Should I apply a bandwidth filter to the E and B fields and then calculate the Poynting vector, or should I directly apply the bandwidth filter to the Poynting vector?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: take a windowed Fourier transform of the time function

Comment: @hyportnex , tnx, Is your point to take the STFT from the electromagnetic or Poynting vector? The goal is to calculate the energy in a specific frequency range.

Comment: take the stft of either the $E$ or $H$ (not $S= E\times H$) , then calculate the magnitude square of it to estimate power spectrum density.